# Adding Two Large Numbers Using Stacks C++

Tags: c++, stack, stringstream

I'm trying to add two arbitrarily large numbers using `stack<int>`. What's the problem with my code?

My resultStack seems to be getting the first value correct but it discarding the remaining digits.

[My code can be found here at ideone](http://ideone.com/m0eMlo)

Below is a portion of my code:

```
    int carry=0, op1=0, op2=0;
    while (true) {
            op1=0,op2=0;
            if (stack1.empty() && stack2.empty()) break;
            if (!stack1.empty()) { op1 = stack1.top(); stack1.pop(); }
            if (!stack2.empty()) { op2 = stack2.top(); stack2.pop(); }
            int opTotal = 0;
            opTotal = op1 + op2 + carry;
            resultStack.push(opTotal%10);
            if (opTotal >= 10) carry = 1; else carry = 0;
    }
```

Comment: So the input has least significant digit on the top of the stack but the output has the most significant digit on the top?

Comment: @brianbeuning but that shouldn't matter. In the end you can reverse the stack and you will be fine.

Comment: @DiscreteGenius thats because your stack1 and stack2 don't get the values right, other than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `stringstream` to convert, which by the way caused the problem in your implementation, you can just do

```
stack.push(input[i] - '0');
```

[EDIT] Test: http://ideone.com/b2n5l9